# Как правильно использовать GitLab.com?

Tags: gitlab

Выбрали для совместной деятельности GitLab.com, но это первый наш опыт совместного ведения проекта. Как грамотней использовать GitLab.com: с одним общим аккаунтом или создавать для каждого свой?

У нас сейчас вариант `1`, но хотим уточнить, правильно ли мы понимаем вариант `2`. Может есть ещё варианты?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для каждого юзера свой, естественно. Юзеров можно добавить в общую группу с общими репозиториями

Comment: Мне кажется вторая схема уж слишком сложная) Все зависит от проекта, его объема и сложности. Я работаю по первой схеме. Но у меня и нет больших проектов, где одна строчка кода может все поломать.

Comment: `push`-права у двоих — это уже головная боль (говорю из собственного опыта), так как накладывает довольно много ограничений на процесс. Например, в такой схеме второй не имеет права делать `rebase` в тестовом бранче (если такой имеется, а как правило имеется в серьёзных проектах). Как раз я с co-maintainer'ом в процессе поиска обходного пути этой проблемы (мы решили уже кое-что проверить, пока тест-драйв).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я тоже работаю с GitLab. Мы сделали один аккаунт, чисто для хранения наших проектов. Естественно, закрытый. Каждый отдельный разработчик создает свой аккаунт отдельно. Затем, кто-то из вас расшаривает доступ к главному аккаунту(где лежит ваш проект) для всех разработчиков. Вы создаете свои дочерние ветки, куда вносите свои изменения, а потом кто-то заливает их в главную. Вот и все, собственно. 
Не говорю, что это правильно, но мы так работаем.